# how do I kill a zeopack without restarting zeo?

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

It seems that in using the zeopack script, the zeopack script returns to the shell after signalling zeo to do a pack on a database. How can I kill a zeopack operation in zeo without bringing down the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to kill the pack is to restart the server:

```
bin/zeoctl restart
```

Clients should reconnect automatically.

The server starts the packing in a separate thread to handle the packing but offers no 'stop' hook.